# Closing of form by property

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, winforms, listview

Im creating a new instance of a form when i double click a list view item. .key is a public property i created for that form

```
 Dim F2 As New NewForm()
        F2.Name = "NewForm" & session.remoteIpAddress.ToString
        F2.Key = session.sessionID
        F2.Show()`
```

Can someone tell me how I can check that an instance of NewForm with a particular key value is open and if yes close it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `OpenForms` for it.

```
For Each frm As Form In Application.OpenForms
   If TypeOf frm Is NewForm Then
      Dim nf As NewForm = DirectCast(frm, NewForm)
      If nf.Key = "some key" Then
         nf.Close()
         Exit For
      End If 
   End If 
Next
```